# java webservices in axis

Tags: java, web-services, client

I am new to web services.I am writing webservices using axis2 1.4 in eclipse 3.5 and using tomcat 5.5.I wrote webservice a in dynamic web project and created a webservice client for this webservice.The client consists of a jsp page which must call the webservice.Can anyone please tell how to use the stub in the jsp to invoke the webservice.I need to know asap.

Answer (score 0):

First, "Axis2" and "Axis 1.4" are quite different.  You should understand that distinction first.

For Axis 1.4:
You'll probably need to get most or all of the Axis 1.4 jar files into your web app's .war file.

You'll probably need to run WSDL2Java, using the web service URL, to get client-side stubs.

After that, you'll have to figure it out.  SOAP lets service designers do their own thing. You'll have to provide and fill out client side objects that consitute the arguments to the SOAP call.  After figuring out how to make the SOAP call, you'll have to decide how to decode the answer.  I use "decode" not in any technical sense, but rather in the sense of parsing through whatever the return object is, and figuring out what the pieces of it mean.

Comment: thanks but can u please put it in simpler terms.I have downloaded axis2 version 1.4 and configured axis in eclise.